# Did my electrolysis experiment produce NaOH?

Tags: electrolysis

I recently conducted an electrolysis experiment on saltwater, hoping to obtain chlorine gas and sodium hydroxide. The experiment ran for approximately 12 hours, powered by a 9V battery. To my surprise, I ended up with a peculiar white substance. I suspect it might be sodium hydroxide, but I'm not entirely sure. The concentration of water is so high that further stirring doesn't seem to dissolve any more of this mysterious substance. Has anyone encountered a similar result in their experiments? Can you confirm if this white substance is indeed NaOH? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1. "a peculiar white substance." Where? What test for NaOH have you tried? 2. Choice of 9-volt battery is poor, since the current capacity is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not electrolyze $\ce{NaCl}$ solutions, if you want to obtain chlorine gas. I explain why.

If salt water is electrolyzed, the first reactions on the electrodes are :

$$\ce{Cathode : 2 H2O + 2 e- -> 2 OH- + H2}$$
$$\ce{Anode : 2 Cl- -> Cl2 + 2 e-}$$

As a consequence, $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ are produced on the electrodes, and $\ce{OH-}$ is emitted in the solution at the cathode. But $\ce{Cl2}$ is partially soluble in water, and goes into solution at the anode. After a while the negative ions $\ce{OH-}$ migrate to the anode (like $\ce{Cl-}$) where they meet the dissolved $\ce{Cl2}$ molecules and react according to :
$$\ce{Cl2 +  2 OH- ->  Cl- + ClO- + H2O}$$ No free chlorine gas $\ce{Cl2}$ is produced any more at the anode, as it is consumed to create the hypochlorite ion $\ce{ClO-}$ The obtained solution is called "bleach". Now if this bleach is slightly heated, the hypochlorite ions disproportionate according to : $$\ce{3 ClO- -> ClO3^- + 2 Cl-}$$ So the solution contains now three negative ions containing chlorine atoms : $\ce{Cl-, ClO-, ClO3^-}$, instead of one !
And now $4$ possible reactions may occur at the anode, due to the negative ions  $\ce{Cl-, OH-, ClO-, and ClO3-}$. I will not give here the four different anodic reactions produced by these four ions.

**So please do not electrolyze salt solutions to get gaseous chlorine** without special equipment to prevent the contact between $\ce{Cl2}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in solution.

I do not know the nature of your white substance. But it is not $\ce{NaOH}$, because $\ce{NaOH}$ is extremely soluble in water. It may be $\ce{NaCl, NaClO, NaClO3}$, or something else.